# AbiWord: [file path/ test] is not a valid file name?

Tags: python, django, python-os, abiword

Working on document conversion from **docx, doc to pdf**. Get to know about **Abiword** which can convert documents from one file format to others. Using python with the os module which supposes to execute my command. This is working properly files with no spaces files but whenever there is a **file with spaces** it is giving this error. Tried to print command and checked is it right or wrong, But the command is right.

```
def saveDocx(files, user):
destination = Path.joinpath(MEDIA_ROOT, user, "trash")
current_doc_files = list()
for file in files:
    fs = FileSystemStorage(location=destination)
    filename = fs.save(file.name, file)
    filename = os.path.join(destination, filename)
    current_doc_files.append(filename)
print("doc files---->", current_doc_files)
return current_doc_files, destination

def convToPdf(current_doc_files, user):
    current_pdf_files = list()
    for file in current_doc_files:
        cmd = "abiword --to=pdf {}".format(file)
        print("----cmd----", cmd)
        try:
            os.system(cmd)
            pdf_file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '.pdf'
            print("converted ", pdf_file_name)
            current_pdf_files.append(pdf_file_name)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("--------Exception--------")
            print(ex)
    return current_pdf_files
```

creating web app on pythonanywhere, They have provided Abiword word processor. Have a look to output on
**When a file with no space**

```
doc files----> ['/home/trash/test.docx']
**2020-11-08 06:10:20 ----cmd---- abiword --to=pdf /home/trash/test.docx**
2020-11-08 06:10:21 Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
2020-11-08 06:10:21 Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
2020-11-08 06:10:21 #012** (abiword:12): WARNING **: clutter failed 0, get a life.
2020-11-08 06:10:21 Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
2020-11-08 06:10:21 Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
2020-11-08 06:10:21 #012(abiword:12): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
**2020-11-08 06:10:21 converted  /home/trash/test.pdf**
```

When a file with spaces comes in the picture, gives error as below

```
doc files----> ['/home/trash/test test.docx']
**2020-11-08 05:46:50 ----cmd---- abiword --to=pdf /home/test test.docx**
2020-11-08 05:46:50 Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
2020-11-08 05:46:50 Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
2020-11-08 05:46:50 #012** (abiword:10): WARNING **: clutter failed 0, get a life.
2020-11-08 05:46:50 Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
2020-11-08 05:46:50 Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
**2020-11-08 05:46:50 AbiWord: [/home/trash/test] is not a valid file name.**
```

**I have alternate solution replacing spaces with an underscore but want to know what is wrong with this.**

Comment: Spaces are perfectly valid in filenames.  However, if you are using such a filename as a command line argument, you need to enclose it in quotes.

Comment: will formatting filename  in quotes for 'with spaces' and 'non spaced files' work or I have to change my logic ?

Comment: Using quotes is safe in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for basics. Did one line change cmd = "abiword --to=pdf '{}'".format(file) in convToPdf method.